# iOS8 plugin pinterest.ShareExtension interrupted

Tags: ios8, pinterest, ios8-share-extension

I have an iOS app that uses UIActivityViewController for sharing.  When I try to share via Pinterest I see the Pinterest share dialog very briefly and then it disappears.

The following message is printed to the log:

```
plugin pinterest.ShareExtension interrupted
```

What is causing this error?  What do I need to do to make Pinterest sharing work?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had a `UIActivityItemSource` to generate my share link.  I was able to resolve this issue by returning an `NSString` rather than `NSURL` to the Pinterest extension.

```
if ([activityType isEqualToString:PinterestExtentionType]) {
    //Unclear why but passing an NSURL to the Pinterest iOS8 extention results in it instantly closing
    return shareUrlString;
} else {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:shareUrlString];
}
```

Comment: hi am struggling with the same issue can you please send where to add this code